# Click Event Unbinded after Server Side Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm facing an issue on Click event of button. Kindly have a look at the following Javascript code.

```js
$(function () {
            
            UploadBtnDisableEvents();
            
            function UploadBtnDisableEvents() {
                var buttonUpload = $('#' + '<%= imgBtnDocUpload.ClientID %>');
                var txtfile = $('#' + '<%= filUpload.ClientID %>');
                var txtname = $('#' + '<%= txtDocName.ClientID %>');

                buttonUpload.on('click', function () {
    
                    validateControls(txtfile, txtname)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            buttonUpload.prop('disabled', true);
                            buttonUpload.removeAttr('href');
                        }, 10);

                    }
                });

                var validateControls = function (file, docname) {
                    var inputname = docname.val();
                    var inputfile = file.val();
                    if (inputname == "" || inputfile == null || inputfile == "" || inputfile == null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

This code works perfectly when intially page is loaded. When user click on upload button, button is disabled and server call is intiated. In Code behind at the end of button click button is again re-enabled. It's purpose is to stop user from clicking button again. Now when user click on delete button this click event which is bound using .on event is unbinded and when user again clicks on upload button, It is not disabled. Kindly give me your suggestions. By the way on delete complete page is reloaded which is why it's not rebinding the button with event. Thanks.

**Note** : Kindly if you require more information just mention in comments. Controls we have used are anthem controls for ajax call purpose.

Comment: and by the way i forgot to mention that i have also tried to run script at the end of deletebutton from serverside but it didn't worked. Here is the code.

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript: UploadBtnDisableEvents(); ", False)

Comment: Perhaps the button submits? If it does, change it to `buttonUpload.on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault();` - I assume you want to ajax the form content to the server and not reload the page?

Comment: @mplungjan i don't think so this is an issue. This is not form submit button. This is server side button.

Comment: What is "a server side button" ?

Comment: server side cotrol. As i'm working in Asp.net WebForms.

Comment: What does this all translate to in HTML/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of hard work i got solution of my question. In case of callback what happened is complete DOM is not loaded so what i did is i have registered my UploadBtnDisableEvents function. Here is the line which i have wrote on callback button click.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript: DisableControls(); ", True)
```

Above code re-register my script when callback completes.